# Enable visual editing of a .cs file using WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

We currently manage and edit all of our c# winform based interface strictly with the text editor in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there anyway we could take our source fies and make it possible for us to edit them with the visual winform editor ?

Comment: Why didn't you do that in the first place? Can you show us a simple sample form?

Comment: if the location of one control is dependent on another then you cannot edit it with the winform editor!

Comment: I inherited that part of the project from other team members who were very new to the technology.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your .cs files a designer.cs and a .resx file, Visual Studio will allow you to open them up in the visual editor.  The catch is that you will have to create a `partial class` of your original .cs object and move the code for the visual elements into the Designer.cs file.  So if you have a file

```
SomeClass.cs
```

you will need to add

```
SomeClass.cs
    SomeClass.designer.cs
    SomeClass.resx
```

Once you add them, visual studio will automatically figure out they are supposed to be related and allkow you to open them in the visual editor.

Comment: Sure, but you might have a better time just recreating the forms from scratch instead of trying to port them over into partial classes.